Problems and Solutions for an increased amount of tick data in Kdb+/q
If a lot of data has been brought into the tick environment at once, what are the problems and what are potential solutions?
Potentially put the tickerplant on batching mode? Potentially run GC more often and increase the amount of memory available to the processes.

https://code.kx.com/q/wp/rt-tick/  |   https://www.defconq.tech/docs/architecture/plain | https://code.kx.com/q/kb/kdb-tick/

Can you provide more details about the specific use case? Your question is quite vague. KDB is quite good handling a lot of data, so the TP shouldn't be a problem. I wouldn't run the main TP in batch mode, if you need batch mode, create a CTP (chained TP) and run that one in batch mode. Let all slow subscribers subscribe to the CTP. GC also has its trade-off. You can read about GC here https://www.defconq.tech/docs/concepts/garbageCollection
Overall, it pretty much depends on your use case, so if you can provide more details you might get the answer you are looking for
